# How to store a scanned value into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, store

I'm having a problem trying to store a scanned value from a text file into an array. The error I receive is cannot convert from string to Month.  Month is an object that is in another class ex public Month(String line){}

The point of the program is to scan a file line by line, store the salaries from each month and compute the total salary at the end. The error I receive is cannot convert from string to Month.  Month is an object that is in another class ex public Month(String line){}

```
private void readMonths() {
    skipHeader();

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {

        String line= in.nextLine(); 

        if(line.length()>0){
            theMonths[monthCount]= line;
            monthCount++;
        } else {
            monthCount=monthCount;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The error I receive is cannot convert from string to Month. Month is an object that is in another class ex public Month(String line){}

Create Month object.

```
String line= in.nextLine(); 
Month month= new Month(line);
```

Now add to `array`.

so

```
 theMonths[monthCount]= month;
```